# Constructor being called for no reason

Tags: actionscript-3, constructor

I got this class, let's call it: Klass.

The class Klass has a parameter for its constructor that is an array with a default value of null.

I create an object of the class Klass inside another class, lets call it: "MotherClass".

Now is when it gets weird, after I instance the object Klass, the constructor of Klass gets called again, just right after the constructor of the MotherClass ends (I placed a breakpoint and I followed step by step), with null constructor parameters.

The thing is, I don't have the stack trace of anything that is calling the constructor of Klass for the second time, no clue what could be calling that constructor again...

Any ideas?

Thanks.

(Klass implements an interface, and I'm making an instance using an array, not sure if that is affecting anything)

added code as requested:

this is the class MotherKlass:

```
public class Unit extends EntityVO{

    public function Unit(level:int = 1)
            {
                //init vars and stuff
                //...
                //

                initLevelData();
                applyLevel = level;

            }

            private function initLevelData():void {

                levelData[1] = [500,  [[Spawn, this.entityToSpawn.type, this.entityToSpawn.level, 120]], "unit_level1"];
                levelData[2] = [1000, [[Spawn, this.entityToSpawn.type, this.entityToSpawn.level,  90]], "unit_level2"];
                levelData[3] = [2000, [[Spawn, this.entityToSpawn.type, this.entityToSpawn.level,  80]], "unit_level3"];
                levelData[4] = [5000, [[Spawn, this.entityToSpawn.type, this.entityToSpawn.level,  60]], "unit_level4"];

            }

            override public function set applyLevel(level:int):void {

                power     = power / maxPower * levelData[level][0]; 
                maxPower  = levelData[level][0];
                behavior  = levelData[level][1];

                for (var i:int = 0; i < behavior.length; i ++){
                    _behaviorSteps[i] = new behavior[i][0](behavior[i].slice(1));
                    _behaviorReqs.push(_behaviorSteps[i].req);
                }

            }
        }
    }   
}
```

and this is Klass:

```
public class Spawn {

    public class Spawn implements IBehavior
        {
            private var _entityType:String;
            private var _entityLevel:int;
            private var _spawnRate:int;

            public function Spawn(params:Array = null){
                //had to put the if because of the second weird call to the constructor with null
                if(params){
                    _entityType = params[0];
                    _entityLevel = params[1];
                    _spawnRate  = params[2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a very simplified version of your class definitions for MotherClass and Klass?

Comment: Not seeing a stack trace in your breakpoint can be a sign that you arrived at that point via some asynchronous mechanism. Maybe there are other reasons for it. But that would be my guess. And that's all we can do w/out seeing any code :)

Comment: Another wild guess - your Klass is a descendant of DisplayObject, and an instance of that is placed on your stage within Adobe Flash CS. This way, these instances get instantiated with default values, so you receive a constructor call you have detected.

Comment: Added the two classes that I mentioned, simplified. @Vesper nope :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm receiving an instance of the class Unit throught Cirrus, and using RegisterClassAlias to deserialize the object. When I do that, seems like an instance of Spawn must be automatically instantiated for some reason. That is why you cant pass ojbects without default arguments. In this case, it throws an error because I'm using (params[0]) the argument that is null. I use Cirrus in other parts of my code, and it works ok because there are all ints and strings in their parameters constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what appears to be happening:

You have a setter for `applyLevel` which is overriding the super class' setter. I think your super class setter is also getting executed. Some observations that lead me to this conclusion:

- your setter method overrides the super class method, but no where does it do `super.applyLevel = level`. This means that in the super class, the storage variable that should be keeping the level value is uninitialized. An uninitialized integer in Actionscript defaults to 0.
- you mention that the second invocation of `Spawn`'s constructor has no parameters. This occurs because your array of `levelData` starts out at index 1. So index 0 of this array is null.
- so the super class version of the `applyLevel` setter method is passing in the null element from above.

I think these facts are 100% correct.

What's not clear to me is who is calling the super class' version of `applyLevel` Perhaps the super class (`EntityVO`) is doing that in it's constructor ... Hopefully this should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that is not what is  happening in this case. What is happening, is that I'm receiving an instance of the class Unit throught Cirrus, and using RegisterClassAlias to deserialize the object. When I do that, seems like an instance of Spawn must be automatically instantiated for some reason. That is why you cant pass ojbects without default arguments. In this case, it throws an error because I'm using (params[0]) the argument that is null. I use Cirrus in other parts of my code, and it works ok because there are all ints and strings in their parameters constructors.